# Firefox extension to save tabs?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, browser-tabs

I'm looking for some Firefox (4 or 5) extension to save a group of tabs (better if can be done directly in Panorama view).
What I mean by "Save tabs" is not to restore them when Firefox starts.

I always have the browser opened and a LOT of tabs (work and personal life related) eating my RAM. So when I'm not working, I would want a way to save those tabs but keep them closed while I still use Firefox. So when I have to start working again, I will restore that saved tabs back again.

I know I could use something like Read It Later, but I really need a way to say "hey, save this group of tabs and close them". RIL makes me do it per tab, which is annoying since I'm used to have A LOT.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Session Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/session-manager/)** is a great add-on that allows you to save your open tabs but I am unsure if it works on Firefox 4/5.

> Session Manager saves and restores the state of all or some windows - either when you want it or automatically at startup and after crashes. It can also automatically save the state of open windows individually.

[image]

Comment: From the page you linked to: Works with Firefox 3.5 - 7.0a1.

So should be fine for 4 and 5.

Comment: I use it on 4. Not sure about 5.

Answer (score 8):

This is built in functionality.

Right click on a tab and choose 'Bookmark all tabs'.

Enter a folder name, e.g. 'session1'.

Now close all tabs - choose one you want to keep open, e.g. http://superuser.com, right click on the the tab and select 'close all other tabs'.

To restore your tab set, go to bookmarks, go down to the 'session1' folder and select 'Open all in tabs'.

You can now go into bookmarks and delete the 'session1' folder, or keep it for later on.

Comment: +1 for the nice workaround. But anyway I find Session Manager easier to mantain several different sessions (with auto-save). thanks anyway!

Answer (score -1):

I typed tabs on the addons website,

There are many you can choose from:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=tabs&cat=1%2C0&x=0&y=0

Answer (score -1):

You could use the [Mozilla Archive Format](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/212/?src=api) Firefox addon:

> It provides the following advantages over the built-in save system:
>
> - A complete page can be saved as a single file (web archive)
> - You can name files using the title of the page (title save)
> - The saved pages are faithful to the original (exact save)
>
> [image]

Or you can use [SaveALL!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/saveall/?src=api)

Comment: This answer only consists of links. I find it unclear how to achieve what OP asks using the mentioned addons.

Comment: To add to Tomáš Zato's comment, it isn't clear how either product solves the problem posed in the question.